# Ensure two functions execute one after the other, where the first function has an asynchronous call inside it

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I am trying to use the async.js library to achieve the following:

- I have two functions: function `a()` and function `b()`
- I want function `a()` to execute first until completion, then I want function `b()` to execute until completion
- Function `a()` has a call to another asynchronous function inside of it

So far I have gathered I should be using the `series()` function from the async library. This is what I have so far:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
       var someResult = a();
       callback(null, someResult);
    },
    function(callback) {
        var someOtherResult = b();
        callback(null, someOtherResult);
    }
],
function(err, results) {
    console.log('Yay');
});
```

This is pretty similar to the code outlined in the documentation for async.js, but inside `a()` there is some other async activity going on.

I want to wait until all activity inside of `a()` has finished before executing `b()`. Is this possible? If I need to modify the contents of `a()`, what would need to be done? I'm aware that this sort of question goes against how things are supposed to be written in node (and js in general), but the async operation going on inside of `a()` is a database query.

Happy to give more info if needed!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that putting the call to "b" inside the callback of the async  function called by "a" is not an option?

Comment: @lucas Yeah it's a possibility, but it makes for less readable code. If it's necessary then I could do it.

Comment: If `a` is asynchronous - what does it return? Any chance it returns a promise?

Comment: @zerkms Unfortunately not :( `a` isn't. It's a fairly straightforward function that performs some db operations then returns.

Comment: @DaveCooper how would you know `a` has completed doing its async stuff if it does not expose it in any way? "performs some db operations then returns" --- if it "performs-then returns` then it's synchronous.

Comment: @zerkms inside `a()` there is a database operation occurring. The function that performs the db operation is asynchronous and has it's own callback. I want to wait until that operation has finished before `a()` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All async functions must accept callbacks (or return a promise). Otherwise it's not possible to execute something after the async function has completed.

So, since `a()` is async. I'd assume that your example:

```
var someResult = a();
```

is a typo. It should be:

```
a(function(someResult){
   // ...
})
```

There is no way around this. You cannot pause the interpreter and wait for an async function to complete because pausing the interpreter will also pause the event loop causing the async function to never complete.

If `a()` is properly written, you should be able to just do this:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
       a(function(someResult){
           callback(null, someResult);
       });
    },
    function(callback) {
        var someOtherResult = b();
        callback(null, someOtherResult);
    }
],
function(err, results) {
    console.log('Yay');
});
```

If not, send `a()` back to the person who wrote it and tell him he's doing it wrong.

Comment: Man, that was a fantastic explanation! The author of `a()` was me and don't you worry, I told him he was doing it wrong. I am new'ish to writing async code and this has just been the lightbulb moment in my brain! Thank you so much for the great help! Shoot me your email address and I'll send you some beer!